# How to push an array in a multidimensional array into a specific subarray in another multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = array(299945 => [13654 => [9917 => [0 => '0', 9 => '9', 33 => '33']]]);
$array2 = array(13654 => [9940 => [0 => '0']]);
```

Each of these are created from different DBQueries which create these results.

I know want to take the '9940' key from `$array2` and push it into `$array1` so that it will be another element in the `13654` array. Thus the final result would be:

`$array1 = array(299945 =>[13654 => [9917 => [0 => '0', 9 => '9', 33 => '33'], 9940 => [0 => '0']]])`

How can I do this?

Comment: Is the key you are looking for in first array always located on second level (depth)? Or do you want to search for the key 9940 recursively in the array? So the key may also be located in other sub arrays much deeper in your first array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways of doing this, here's one that uses `array_replace_recursive()`:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain');

$array1 = array(299945 => [13654 => [9917 => [0 => '0', 9 => '9', 33 => '33']]]);
$array2 = array(13654 => [9940 => [0 => '0']]);

$array3 = array_replace_recursive($array1, [key($array1) => $array2]);

print_r($array3);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [299945] => Array
        (
            [13654] => Array
                (
                    [9917] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [9] => 9
                            [33] => 33
                        )

                    [9940] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Although this solution correctly uses array_merge_recursive, it will not work if you change keys, even with exactly such an array structure

Comment: @splash58 change _which_ keys?

Comment: The initial key `299945`. Without the OP stipulating the schema of the given arrays, this is the best answer I can give.

Comment: @e_i_pi Are you shure? :)  Use `[key($array1) => $array2]`, at least

Comment: Is it always going to be in that format though? i.e. `array($key1 => $schema1), array($schema2)`. It's an unknown, I wasn't going to assume that was always the pattern

Comment: It's a technicality is what I'm saying, not disagreeing with you, just pointing out that it's open to interpretation

Comment: I think that we will see new question for that in some time, or OP will ask you again here, because structure of array1 as [12=>[13=>], [14=>]]  seems to be very possible

Comment: Fair enough, I've updated the answer to reflect your amendment

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a [union of two arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php), there is not much to it:

`$array1 += $array2`

You should probably think about more complex situation with duplicate keys and issues like that, so I usually find [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to be the better tool for adding two arrays together.